# Designing a macro, regex expression or approach for importing first search result from Google

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one cell in a Google spreadsheet, which contains "apple". In the column next to it, I am trying to take the cell with the text "apple", run that through Google search, and return the URL of the first search result that comes up.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution to this issue. Google does not allow scraping Google Search via Google Sheets. Any such attempt will result in `#N/A` error.

[image: 0]